# Mariadb / MySQL connection in time_wait for 2 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

when I run the following php script it shows that the database port is in time_wait mode for 2 minutes before it drops the connection.

PHP code:

```
<?php
$db_host = "127.0.0.1";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "pass";
$db_dbase = "database";
$mysqli = new mysqli("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass", "$db_dbase");

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

IPTSTATE

shows the database tcp connection in time_wait mode for the next 2 minutes.

I'm just wondering how to I get it to drop the connection as soon as the php script has finished?

Comment: That's pretty normal networking for socket connections that were opened and not currently being used. Short of restarting your network daemon you won't be able to manually do anything about it.

Answer (score -1):

I would suspect that this is to do with `Persistent connections` being set on in your `php.ini` for MySQL.

[Persistent connections manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)

Basically, once the connection is 'closed', it hangs around for a while in case it is going to be used again (which in a large web application, is quite likely). Then, if it is needed again it saves the time and resource of creating a new connection as there is one already waiting.

The settings you want to check in your `php.ini` are:

```
[MySQLi]

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-persistent
mysqli.max_persistent = -1

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow-persistent
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
```

Changing these may change the behavior you are seeing.